# Trigger that will stop from deleting if a foreign key record is not deleted

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I've got two tables: Countries (Id, Name) and Cities (Id, CountryId, Name), CountryId is a Foreign Key to Cities.

I need a trigger that will prevent deleting certain Cities if the Country is not being deleted, in other words certain Cities can only be deleted when Country is being deleted.

```
CREATE TABLE Countries 
(
    Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Name [VARCHAR] (100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Countries VALUES ('Germany'), ('Spain'), ('Italy');

CREATE TABLE Cities 
(
    Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    CountryId [int], 
    Name [VARCHAR] (100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Cities_Countries 
        FOREIGN KEY (CountryId) REFERENCES Countries(Id)
);

INSERT INTO Cities VALUES 
(1, 'Berlin'), (1, 'Dresden'), (2, 'Madrid'), (2, 'Barcelona'), (3, 'Rome'), (3, 'Milano');
```

ERP system allows to delete records both from Cities and Countries (when Country deletion action is called first records from Cities are deleted then from the Countries. I need to block deletion from Cities if Country is not being deleted i.e.

```
DELETE FROM Cities WHERE Name='Berlin' --needs to be stopped
DELETE FROM Countries WHERE Name='Germany' --needs to go
```

Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

As [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin) pointed out, you can't delete a country meanwhile there are cities belonging to this country.

```
DELETE FROM Countries WHERE Name = 'Germany';
```

> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Cities_Countries". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.Cities", column 'CountryId'.

You could change `NO ACTION` by `ON DELETE CASCADE`

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Cities_Countries 
    FOREIGN KEY (CountryId) REFERENCES Countries(Id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But according to your question you want a trigger that blocks delete action for some Cities if it Country still exists.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCities_Delete
ON Cities
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    DELETE c
    FROM   Cities c
    JOIN   deleted d
    ON     c.ID = d.ID
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   Countries
                       WHERE  Id = d.CountryId);
END
```

Then when you try to create the trigger you'll receive next error:

> Msg 2113 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
>   Cannot create INSTEAD OF DELETE or INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER 'trgCities_Delete' on table 'Cities'. This is  because the table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE.

Humm, that's a catch-22 situation.

Ok, let me remove `ON DELETE CASCADE` action and now I try to delete some city.

```
DELETE FROM Cities WHERE Name = 'Barcelona';

SELECT * FROM Cities;

Id | CountryId | Name     
-: | --------: | :--------
 1 |         1 | Berlin   
 2 |         1 | Dresden  
 3 |         2 | Madrid   
 4 |         2 | Barcelona
 5 |         3 | Rome     
 6 |         3 | Milano
```

Barcelona is still there. The trigger works as expected.

Now try to delete 'Spain':

```
DELETE FROM Countries WHERE Name = 'Spain';
```

> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Cities_Countries". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.Cities", column 'CountryId'.

Catch-22 again. I can't delete Barcelona neither Spain!! That's a bit mental.

Let me suggest another approach. If you need to avoid deletes, flag the affected records using some field and let foreign keys do their job.

```
ALTER TABLE Cities ADD Blocked int NULL;

UPDATE Cities
SET    Blocked = 1
WHERE  Name = 'Berlin';
```

Now change the trigger by:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgCities_Delete
ON Cities
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    DELETE c
    FROM   Cities c
    JOIN   deleted d
    ON     c.ID = d.ID
    AND    c.Blocked <> 1;

END

DELETE FROM Cities WHERE Name = 'Berlin';
SELECT * FROM Cities;

Id | CountryId | Name      | Blocked
-: | --------: | :-------- | ------:
 1 |         1 | Berlin    |       1
 2 |         1 | Dresden   |       0
 3 |         2 | Madrid    |       0
 4 |         2 | Barcelona |       0
 5 |         3 | Rome      |       0
 6 |         3 | Milano    |       0
```

Well Berlin still there, now if you want to delete Spain you must delete Madrid and Barcelona before.

```
DELETE FROM Cities WHERE Name IN ('Barcelona', 'Madrid');
DELETE FROM Countries WHERE Name = 'Spain';
SELECT * FROM Cities;

Id | CountryId | Name    | Blocked
-: | --------: | :------ | ------:
 1 |         1 | Berlin  |       1
 2 |         1 | Dresden |       0
 5 |         3 | Rome    |       0
 6 |         3 | Milano  |       0
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ad96e1c72dd4ff0588f81b8c101d0b6)*